# "element:hover's" color attribute not work, what could be the wrongs?

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

I have an element with class "navIcon" and I give it a color and background color.
and I wanna when user hover on this element, it's color change to a black color for exam and background change also.
background color change successfully, but color still same as first color. here is my styles:

```
.navIcon{
    width: 45px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 8px;
    color: #f7f8f8;
}

.navIcon:hover{
    background-color: #f7f8f8;
    color: #3a3e3e; 
}
```

and the html is here:

```
    <div id="userAuth" class="navIcon">
        <i class="icon-user"></i>
    </div>
```

and also i use Font Awesome.

What could be the wrongs?

Comment: Is that the exact order in your css? if .navIcon:hover is in another CSS file or before .navIcon, it will get overridden.

Comment: You could also try `color: #3a3e3e !important; `, but it should not be neccessary, usually

Comment: Please put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your relevant code - as you can see it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/cHzVJ/1/

Comment: where is the LINK ? Let me guess : you are trying to hover on a non-transparent image ?

Comment: @TobSpr both is in same file and :hover writen after base style.
i tried !important also, but the problem still there.

Comment: guys i think there is a higher priority rule that affect on specified element. but i cant find where is that, and google developer tool can't show what is that.
any idea to how to find it?

Comment: @3034K Use [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No ways this won't work, it's just a basic `:hover` so it should work, the only thing I doubt is that your CSS must be having `!important` declaration for `:hover` or another rule with higher specificity.

For example

```
div a {
    color: #f00;  /* Red */
}

div a:hover {
    color: #0f0; /* Green */
}

a:hover {
    color: #0ff;  /* Blue */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7zhJZ/)

Here, `div a:hover` is more specific compared to simple `a:hover` thus, in your case, you must be having a selector with higher specificity or you've `!important` declared.

Comment: you are actually hovering on an anchor. The OP do not mention on 'what' it's hovering.  What about an non-transparent image?

Comment: @MilchePatern If he would be hovering an image, he wouldn't have used color at first place

Comment: duh, i don't noticed that :d
thanks a lot man to remind me a base rule in css. the color changed successfully after i change the selector to: #userAuth:hover i{...}

but i don't know why firefox and chrome developer tool and also firebug, don't show the inherited rule for :hover on this element? :/ maybe a bug.